# How to put icons on desktop in openbox using pcmanfm

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-icons, openbox

So I want to be able to put some icons on my openbox desktop but I am using xubuntu so I don’t have nautilus and I’ve heard you can draw icons to desktop using pcmanfm.Is that true and if so what command do I have to run at autostart

Comment: Please edit your question and add some punctuation to increase readability. Help your helpers. Then they will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autostart `pcmanfm` with the command `pcmanfm --desktop` to have the file manager manage the desktop, i.e. enable the use of desktop icons and set wallpaper.

Comment: Thanks for the response.